# issues of saving a large scale matrix to mat file

Tags: matlab

I was trying to save a matrix into a mat file, but the Matlab returns the following messages:

> Warning: Variable 'listmatrix' cannot be saved to a MAT-file whose version is older than 7.3.
>   To save this variable, use the -v7.3 switch.
>   Skipping...

What does it mean for "use the -v7.3 switch"?

Should I use

`save testresult.mat -v7.3   listmatrix`

or sth else?

Comment: Did you try it? Yes, your interpretation is correct. Not sure why you cannot use the new MAT file format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick google search says yes. Try

```
save -v7.3 testresult.mat listmatrix
```

How big is your object? (Do `whos listmatrix`)
You could potentially save memory by using different data type such as uint8.

- http://www.mathworks.ch/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/243327
- http://www.mathworks.de/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/307845

Answer (score 4):

Hi i thought I’d reply to this thread as I’ve been trying to figure out how to save a large (>2 GB) .mat file in matlab v7 (v7.1.0.183) (R14) and finally found a solution.

If you try to use the save command you will get the following error:

```
save('test.mat', 'data');
```

> Warning: Variable 'data' cannot be saved to a MAT-file because its
>   storage requirements exceed 2^31 bytes. This limitation will be
>   addressed in a future release. Consider storing this variable in HDF5
>   file format (see HDF5WRITE). Skipping...

The solution is to write a HDF5 file instead:

```
hdf5write('test.hdf5', '/dataset1', data);
```

You can then read the data back into matlab using:

```
hdf5read('test.hdf5', '/dataset1');
```