# Matlab error saving containers.Map()

Tags: matlab, save

I try to save a map as a *.mat file which is quite big. (somewhere around 4 or 5gigs. I cannot be sure because I could never save the file...)

the map is generated by:

```
[amap, ~] = load_audio(config);
```

and saved later on by

```
save('audioMap', 'amap');
```

Now the generated file is only 218 bytes but no errors occur. Trying to read the contents of the file with `whos('-file', 'audioMap.mat')` results in the following error:

```
Warning: Unable to read some of the variables due to unknown MAT-file error.
```

every record of the map is a cell with 6 values. Now querying the size of the map in the Matlab workspace results in the following output:

```
Name         Size            Bytes  Class             Attributes
amap      2279x1               112  containers.Map
```

Now clearly the size is not correct but I am able to iterate through the map and all data is present. When querying the size of a record it is approximately 2.5MB.

I also tried to save the variable from the workspace with right-click and save-as with the same result.
Anyone got any ideas why Matlab is not able to properly save this map?

Comment: Have you tried saving it using the [`-v7.3` flag](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html#inputarg_version). It's clear that MATLAB is thinking that the object is much smaller than it is so it wouldn't issue the normal warning about using this flag.

Comment: Also, what's actually *inside* each of those map elements? Are they custom objects?

Comment: It might be an issue with the serialisation which is required to save objects. Is the containers.Map your only object oriented data structure? If so try `amap_struct=struct(amap)` and save the resulting struct. There is no automatism to get back the objects, but you could verify if all data is present after loading (amap_struct.serialisation.values)

Comment: @Suever so the layout of one record is: double vector, double vector, string, string, integer, string. So no custom object just plain Matlab data types

Comment: @Suever adding the -7.3 flag helped and solved the issue. Thank you!

Comment: @LukasHäfliger This may be worth [filing a bug report](https://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/) with The Mathworks. I believe that it's a fundamental limitation of objects (MATLAB can't determine their true size) but this is pretty bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You where attempting to write a MAT-File version 7.0 which [has a maximum variable size of 2^31 bytes](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/mat-file-versions.html)=2GB

When you attempt to write Variables larger than the limit, the expected behaviour would be to [receive a warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364003/issues-of-saving-a-large-scale-matrix-to-mat-file) when saving the variable.

> Warning: Variable 'varname' cannot be saved to a MAT-file whose version is older than 7.3. To save this variable, use the -v7.3 switch. Skipping...

For some reason the warning was not raised, but beeing unable to write such large objects is the expected behaviour.